# Wordpress Scheduled Post Error : "Missed schedule"

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have 2000 scheduled posts in Wordpress. I want to change the schedule dates and update mysql database.

```
update wp_posts SET post_date  = FROM_UNIXTIME(
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + FLOOR(0 + (RAND() * 31557600)))
  WHERE post_status = 'future';

update wp_posts SET post_modified = post_date
WHERE post_status = 'future';


update wp_posts SET post_modified_gmt = post_date
WHERE post_status = 'future';


update wp_posts SET post_date_gmt = post_date
WHERE post_status = 'future';
```

I'm currently getting an error on Wordpress admin panel. it is "Missed schedule".

How can I solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.